# enable disable dropdownlist with respect to checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have one `dropdownlist` and a `checkbox` in `RadGrid`.

I have set dropdown `Enabled="false"` initially. So on page load, dropdownlist will be disabled, now if I check any checkbox from RadGrid, dropdown should be enabled.

Checkbox:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CheckBoxTemplateColumn">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleRowSelection"
            AutoPostBack="True" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="headerChkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleSelectedState"
            AutoPostBack="True" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Dropdownlist:

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddlAction" Enabled="false" DefaultMessage="Action" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="action" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAction_SelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server">
   <Items>
       <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="" Value="" />
       <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Refresh Mail Status" Value="Refresh Mail Status" />
       <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Send All" Value="Send All" />
       <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Send Selected" Value="Send Selected"/>
       <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Remove" Value="Remove" />
   </Items>
</telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ddlAction_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, DropDownListEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    chk.FindControl("CheckBox1");

    if (!chk.Checked) {
        ddlAction.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

ToggleRowSelection

```
protected void ToggleRowSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((sender as CheckBox).NamingContainer as GridItem).Selected = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;
            bool checkHeader = true;
            foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in radgridCCBList.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
                if (!(dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)
                {
                    checkHeader = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            GridHeaderItem headerItem = radgridCCBList.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Header)[0] as GridHeaderItem;
            (headerItem.FindControl("headerChkbox") as CheckBox).Checked = checkHeader;

        }
```

ToggleSelectedState

```
protected void ToggleSelectedState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox headerCheckBox = (sender as CheckBox);
            foreach (GridDataItem dataItem in radgridCCBList.MasterTableView.Items)
            {
                (dataItem.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox).Checked = headerCheckBox.Checked;
                dataItem.Selected = headerCheckBox.Checked;
            }
        }
```

Here, `ToggleRowSelection` and `ToggleSelectedState` method are to, select particular row of grid when i check a checkbox of that particular row.

Comment: Please provide code where you have added RadDropDownList.  (it would be nice if you will provide your all columns markup/aspx code).

Comment: i have already posted.. RadDropDownList is above RadGrid

Comment: i am referring your tutorials for telerik. hope you can solve it. ;) @JayeshGoyani

Comment: Try to use EditItemTemplate instead of using ItemTemplate

Comment: I think your code says the checkbox methods are "ToggleRowSelection" and "ToggleSelectedState", but you didn't show what those methods do.

Comment: it simply select and dis select RadGrid row. when i check checkbox of particular row. that row should be selected. these methods are for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

Method1:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlAction.Enabled = false;
    }
}

protected void ToggleRowSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateCheckbox();
}

protected void ValidateCheckbox()
{
    bool IsEnabled = false;

    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = item["CheckBoxTemplateColumn"].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            IsEnabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    ddlAction.Enabled = IsEnabled;
}
```

Method2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlAction.Enabled = false;
    }
}


protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateCheckbox(); 
}

protected void ValidateCheckbox()
{
    bool IsEnabled = false;

    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = item["CheckBoxTemplateColumn"].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            IsEnabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    ddlAction.Enabled = IsEnabled;
}
```

Update 1:

```
protected void ValidateCheckbox()
{
    bool IsEnabled = false;

    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = item["CheckBoxTemplateColumn"].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {
            IsEnabled = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    GridHeaderItem headerItem = radgridCCBList.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Header)[0] as GridHeaderItem;
    if ((headerItem.FindControl("headerChkbox") as CheckBox).Checked)
    {
        IsEnabled = true;
    }

    ddlAction.Enabled = IsEnabled;
}
```

Update 2: (To disable only items in RadDropDownList)

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddlAction" DefaultMessage="Action" AutoPostBack="true" DataValueField="action" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="" Value="" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Refresh Mail Status" Value="Refresh Mail Status" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Send All" Value="Send All" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Send Selected" Value="Send Selected" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Remove" Value="Remove" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // To disable "Send All" option in DropDown
    DisableItemInDropDown("Send All");

    // To disable "Remove" option in DropDown
    DisableItemInDropDown("Remove");
}

protected void DisableItemInDropDown(string ddlItemValueText)
{
    foreach (DropDownListItem item in ddlAction.Items)
    {
        if (item.Value == ddlItemValueText)
        {
            item.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just for knowledge. is it possible that if checkbox is not checked, still dropdown will be enabled, but items in dropdownlist will be disabled? any idea?

Comment: I will try and inform you. (In office I don't have access of Telerik DLL)

Comment: logic of selecting row with respect to checkbox is breaking due to your code.

Comment: and if i uncheck checkbox, dropdown is still enabled.

Comment: Please try with Method 2 and let me know if it is not working.

Comment: what about `"headerChkbox"` ? i wanted same for this checkbox too. but its not working with your code sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83866/discussion-between-dinav-ahire-and-jayesh-goyani).

Comment: sir any idea how to disable only items of dropdown??